# Saving output to text file in markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have been working with `H2O` in `Rmarkdown`, and when I wanted to save the output in a text file, just the first part (page) saved, however, it was ok in console

I used following code:

```
fileConn<-file(".\\h2o.randomForest\\output.txt")
writeLines(capture.output(summary(rf1)), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

how can I save all output to a text file?

#### Due to reproducibility request

you can try following code in Rmarkdown

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# import the iris dataset:
# this dataset is used to classify the type of iris plant
# the original dataset can be found at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris
iris <-h2o.importFile("http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv")

# convert response column to a factor
iris['class'] <-as.factor(iris['class'])

# set the predictor names
predictors <-colnames(iris)[-length(iris)]

# split into train and validation
iris_splits <- h2o.splitFrame(data = iris, ratios = .8, seed = 1234)
train <- iris_splits[[1]]
valid <- iris_splits[[2]]

# try using the `estimate_k` parameter:
# set k to the upper limit of classes you'd like to consider
# set standardize to False as well since the scales for each feature are     very close
iris_kmeans <- h2o.kmeans(x = predictors, k = 10, estimate_k = T, standardize = F,
                      training_frame = train, validation_frame=valid, seed = 1234)

# print the model summary to see the number of clusters chosen


fileConn<-file("output2.txt")
writeLines(capture.output(summary(iris_kmeans)), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

Which gives the following outputs

[Console output](https://textuploader.com/deg3r)

[image]

[Rmarkown output](https://textuploader.com/deg3c)

[image]

### New discovery

When you `knit` the Rmarkdown, it is okay but when `run the current chunk`, it is abnormal.

#### Update

Same result on Windows and Ubuntu

[image]

#### sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1258   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Given the details provided, I cannot reproduce this. Using the stock iris example, the output that appears in the console is output to the text file using your code in  a rmarkdown file.

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Comment: Thanks: I had tried with h2o.randomForest!

Comment: okay. I still can't reproduce. The output to the console is the same as in the text file. What part of the output is missing for you please?

Comment: Please reproduce it in `Rmarkdown` and compare the result with console output.

Comment: Hi imi ; yes I ran it in a rmrdown file : [example code in this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185297/imi), output is the same as in the console, as in the rmarkdown outfile, and in the output text file.

Comment: I have uploaded my outputs, please check

Comment: Hi , your edited outputs are giving 404 error: page not found. HAve you tried the code in the chat room that i posted; does it still give different outcomes? This may be a local issue, so can you also edit in the results from `sessionInfo()` please.

Comment: reuploaded ....

Comment: thanks. this is now another model -- neural network. Can you post the output from your kmeans example please so that  it can be reproduced. Even better if you can use the rmd file from the chat link as I know they produce the same output on my pc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185303/discussion-between-imi-and-user20650).

Comment: Thanks for the update @imi. I can't reproduce -- I get the same output in the console and output text file. So this may be some local settings issue. Can you add the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question please - hopefully someone can give advice.

Comment: I will check it on Ubuntu and report the result

Comment: I used Rmarkdown but I also get the same output in the text file as the one in the console.

Comment: please check `run the current chunk`

Comment: It works either way.

Comment: Do you have any specific configuration for the Chunk?

Comment: No, Nothing special. I uploaded some new information

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve but if you want

**Write all output to a text file**

The easiest way to do this is to use Rscript and redirect the output, from command line:

```
Rscript yourscriptfilename.R > output.txt
```

Or directly from R for example via `system` (or `shell` on Windows):

```
system("Rscript yourscriptfilename.R > output.txt")
```

This will run your R script and instead of writing the output to the console write them into output.txt

**knitr to render the `summary` to the output of and R Mardown file**

Just add `summary(iris_kmeans)` to the bottom of your chunk in the R Markdown file

Comment: Thank you, I want to know why the behavior of `writeLines(capture.output(summary(iris_kmeans)), fileConn)` when `run the current chunk` is different from console

Answer (score 0):

I could not actually reproduce your problem; i.e., it works well at my side when I use either **R console**, **knit**, or **Run Current Chunk**.

I would speculate that there is an (obscure) issue with the `file` connection and/or the `writeLines` function. Therefore, I would suggest that you use one of the following options to write the output to the file. I would also recommend that you save the output to a variable before sending it out to the file.

**Option 1:** using `cat` instead of `writeLines`, as follows:

```
fileConn<-file("output2.txt")
output <- capture.output(summary(iris_kmeans))
cat(output, file=fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

**Option 2:** using `cat` with `sink`, as follows:

```
sink("output2.txt")
output <- capture.output(summary(iris_kmeans))
cat(output)
sink()
```

Let me know if that helps.